# Scala - method not recognized in constructor

Tags: scala, constructor

I'm trying to extend javax.swing.Timer, but it only has one constructor, which is

```
Timer(int delay, ActionListener listener)
```

I do not want my subclass in Scala to take a Java `ActionListener` in its constructor. I read in a [very old thread](http://scala-programming-language.1934581.n4.nabble.com/Calling-superclass-constructor-td1987259.html) that "there is no way to call a superclass constructor directly; you have to pass by the primary constructor of your own class", so it looks like I'm stuck with the `ActionListener` in the primary constructor. So I've added an auxiliary constructor thus:

```
case class TimerEvent (source: AnyRef) extends swing.event.Event

class ScalaTimer2 (delay: Int, listener: java.awt.event.ActionListener)
      extends javax.swing.Timer(delay, listener) with swing.Publisher {
  outer =>
  def this(delay: Int) = {
    this(delay, new java.awt.event.ActionListener {
      def actionPerformed(e: java.awt.event.ActionEvent) {
        publish(TimerEvent(outer))   // <-- publish not recogonized
      }
    })
//    publish(TimerEvent(outer)) // <-- publish recognized here
  }
}
```

However I get a compile error `error: not found: value publish` ... why? And how to fix?

Comment: For those looking into this question, be aware of issue SI-4842 which crashes the compiler: https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-4842

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are actually two problems here: both `publish` and `outer` will not be available until the constructor has completed. Scala seems to have a rule that `this` instance cannot be referenced in an auxiliary constructor until the primary constructor has completed. For example, the following will fail to compile:

```
class Foo (x: Unit) { def this() { this(println(this)) } }
```

Rather than an auxiliary constructor, how about defining a factory method on the companion object?

```
object ScalaTimer2 {
  def apply(delay: Int): ScalaTimer2 = {
    lazy val ret: ScalaTimer2 = new ScalaTimer2(delay, new java.awt.event.ActionListener {
      def actionPerformed(e: java.awt.event.ActionEvent) {
        ret.publish(TimerEvent(ret))
      }
    })
    ret
  }
}
```

Note that the forward reference of `ret` requires the use of a `lazy val` instead of just `val`. Presumably `actionPerformed` is not called until the constructor returns, otherwise `ret` will be invalid due to infinite recursion.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a workaround I found in this particular case: send a dummy ActionListener then remove and replace with the real one.

```
class ScalaTimer2 private (delay: Int, listener: java.awt.event.ActionListener)
      extends javax.swing.Timer(delay, listener) with swing.Publisher {
  outer =>

  def this(delay: Int) = 
    this(delay, new java.awt.event.ActionListener {
      def actionPerformed(e: java.awt.event.ActionEvent) { } // dummy
    })
  removeActionListener(listener)

  addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener {
    def actionPerformed(e: java.awt.event.ActionEvent) {
      publish(new TimerEvent(outer))
    }
  })
}
```

Edit: another trick: making the primary constructor `private` so that there's no opportunity to mistakenly try constructing with your own `ActionListener`.

Edit 2: or avoid the auxiliary constructor altogether by passing an anonymous ActionListener in the signature.

**Edit 3 - solved**! : I just read in the Javadoc that the ActionListener passed to the constructor can be null! So all we actually need is:

```
class ScalaTimer2 (delay: Int) extends Timer(delay, null) with Publisher {
  outer =>
  addActionListener(new ActionListener {
    def actionPerformed(e: ActionEvent) {
      publish(new TimerEvent(outer))
    }
  })
}
```